# Bootstrap dropdown animation not working in IE and Firefox

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

I'm making my first website using Bootstrap, and I have the following CSS in my custom.css to make a dropdown in my navbar have a fancy animation:

```
.open > .dropdown-menu {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1, 1);
  transform: scale(1, 1);  
  opacity:1;
}

.dropdown-menu {
  opacity:3;
  -webkit-transform-origin: top;
  transform-origin: top;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;  
  animation-fill-mode: forwards; 
  -webkit-transform: scale(1, 0);
  display: block; 
  transition: all 0.2s linear;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s linear;
}
```

I'm new to web development, and made the rookie mistake of only testing in one browser (Chrome) whilst making my site. I've almost finished my site so I decided to test in other browsers. I discovered that the drop-downs are already opened when I run the site in IE and Firefox, and they can not be toggled.

I discovered that removing/commenting the above CSS fixes the issue in all browsers, but I would really like this animation to work.

Comment: You're missing the non -webkit- prefix for transform: scale(1,0). Also, you don't need -webkit-transition - pretty much any modern browser supports the unprefixed version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well there are few prefixes for doing that in different browsers

`-webkit-`  for **Google chrome**

`-moz-`  for **Firefox**

`-ms-`  for **Internet explorer**

`-o-`  for **Opera**

In your code you can do this

```
.open > .dropdown-menu {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1, 1);
    -moz-transform: scale(1, 1);
    -ms-transform: scale(1, 1);
    -o-transform: scale(1, 1);
    transform: scale(1, 1);
    transform: scale(1, 1);  
    opacity:1;
}
```

Do this in your all modules and in the **keyframes** you are using for the **animation**

Well for example you can watch this vedio [keyframes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Cn5Wh9Ja5bQ)